# when send SMS by Twilio contain link in body become SMS undelivered

Tags: php, laravel, twilio, twilio-php

[image: code]

when send SMS by Twilio contain link in body become SMS undelivered by php Laravel ?
can any one help me in this problem please !
note:

1. my account in Twilio paid
2. i use laravel
3. name package $ composer require twilio/sdk
   please

Comment: Please, do not post images for your code, but the code itself as text

Comment: Maybe the link is considered insecure by either Twilio or the telecom company and hence rejected delivery to safeguard the recipient.

Comment: trying to send a scam link? xD nevermind

Comment: @OMiShah no link from my website for notification user

Comment: Could you post a copy or screenshot of the SMS that you receive, please? That would help to debug the issue.